# Последовательность Паскаль

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Есть задача:

> Назовем последовательность пилообразной, если каждый ее элемент строго больше, своих соседей. По данному числу определите число пилообразных последовательностей длины n, составленных из чисел.

Написал код, но по всей видимости не верный в каких то моментах и выводит не правильное значение переменной result.

```
 var 
 a : array[1..10] of integer;
 i ,k , n, result: integer;

begin

randomize;
writeln('Введите n');
readln(n);
write('Исходная последовательность: ');
for i:=1 to 10 do 
  read(a[i]);

for i:=2 to 9 do begin
 if ((a[i] > a[i-1]) and (a[i]>a[i+1])) then begin
 inc(k);
 if k=n then begin 
 inc(result);
 k:=0;
end;end;end;

writeln(result);
```

Пример ввода данных : 1, 2, 1 , 4, 5 , 3 , 7, 9, 9 , 8

Вывод : 2

Comment: а как, простите, каждый может быть быть больше соседей, если для двух соседних точек мы получаем два противоложных условия? взять точки i=2, i=3. Если каждый боьлше соседей, то A2 > A3, затем переходим к следующей и имеем A3 > A2. Чтобы "пилу" получить, вам нужны не каждый больше, а каждый второй больше. Иначе ваша последовательность будет состоять максимум из трех точек, где средняя больше соседей, или нет?

Comment: ну это да, можно поправить потом, факт в том что result не накапливается

Comment: В "пилообразной" последовательности для всех не-крайних точек выполняется условие `(X[i] - X[i-1]) * (X[i+1] - X[i]) > 0`. Вот его и проверяйте. Для данной конкретной задачи - нужно пройти по массиву и для всех не-крайних точек проверить, получив итоговый массив размера `N-2` с единицами и нулями (выполняется или нет), после чего посчитать в нём количество блоков последовательных единиц длины `n-2`. Что опять же упрощается - определить длины всех последовательных блоков любой длины, и просуммировать `L-n+1` для всех блоков не короче `n-2`.

Comment: *Пример ввода данных* Пример не соответствует заданию. Отсутствует `n`. *Вывод : 2* Ответ верный только при `n=4`.